# Add paragraphe in each page - PDF in Java with itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm usuing iText to generate a PDF file with java.

I want to add a paragraph or some text in each page.

I'm use HTMl tags to format text.

This an example what I'm trying to create.

[image]

And this my code that I use :

```
public pdfing() {


    try {
            com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document(PageSize.A4);
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("fdf.pdf"));
        document.open();
        HTMLWorker htmlWorker = new HTMLWorker(document);
             htmlWorker.parse(new StringReader("text text ..... " +
                    "<h1 style = \"color:#00ff00;\">aaaaa</h1>"));



        document.close();

        } catch(DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I tried document.addPage() but I seem that doesn't exist.

How can I do???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the API call [newPage()](http://api.itextpdf.com/com/itextpdf/text/Document.html#newPage%28%29) to add a new page.